# Angular search function how to revert?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nice little way to search through the data.

```
$scope.searchContacts = function(term) {
  console.log(term)
  $scope.contacts = $scope.contacts.filter(function(contact) {
    var name = contact.name.toLowerCase();
    if(name.indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  });
};
```

This will update the `$scope.contacts` with the input keywords, but when there is a backspace I now have an issue because the objects are removed from the scope. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: How is this being utilized?  Are you using an input along with an ng-repeat to display the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying original array (overwriting it) consider using filters. So you should not change `$scope.contacts` manually.

In controller:

```
$scope.filters = {};

$scope.searchContacts = function() {
    $scope.filters.name = $scope.term;
};
```

And then where you render contacts you would have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:filters">...</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2ENLgUXVUmVdJOO27ZeL?p=preview